# Error get value after call a function the async method is complete?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a sample code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({appId: appId, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

   // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
   FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
         getFlag(1);
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
         getFlag(2);
      } else {
         getFlag(3);
      }
    });   
};
var f = function getFlag(flag){};
alert(f);
```

result is a `function getFlag(flag) {}` , If = 1 is exactly, How to get this value

Answer (score 0):

Couple of points from your code.

1) Calling `getFlag` function will not be executed because you assigned `getFlag` function into a variable `f` . So you need to call the function using `f()` .

2) Your function is an asynchronous call due to that your code `alert(f)` will reached before the function execution .

3) If you want the flag value why wont you just declare a variable and assign it .

```
var flag;
 FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
     this.flag = 1;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
     this.flag = 2;
  } else {
     this.flag = 3;
  }
});
```

Comment: I using option 3) of you, result is "undefined" when alert(flag);

Comment: @ha1tru0n9 Please read the 2nd point . Your function call is asynchronous that's the problem .